# How to cut a string from the end in UIPATH

Tags: substring, uipath

I have this string: "C:\Procesos\rrhh\CorteDocumentos\Cortados\10001662-1_20060301_29_1_20190301.pdf" and im trying to get this part : "20190301". The problem is the lenght is not always the same. It would be: 
"9001662-1_20060301_4_1_20190301".

I've tried this: item.ToString.Substring(66,8), but it doesn't work sometimes.

What can I do?.

Comment: Get the filenamewithout extension using Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method then split the filename by '_' and get the last index of the arry by using count - 1

Answer (score 1):

This is a code example of what I said in my comment.

```
    Sub Main()


        Dim strFileName As String = ""
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\Maniac\Desktop\test")
        Dim aryFi As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.pdf")
        Dim fi As FileInfo

        For Each fi In aryFi

            Dim arrname() As String
            arrname = Split(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name), "_")
            strFileName = arrname(arrname.Count - 1)
            Console.WriteLine(strFileName)
        Next


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using a simple regular expressions, which has the added benefit of including pattern validation.

If you need to get exactly eight numbers from the end of file name (and after an underscore), you can use this pattern:

```
_(\d{8})\.pdf
```

And then this VB.NET line:

```
Regex.Match(fileName, "_(\d{8})\.pdf").Groups(1).Value
```

It's important to mention that Regex is by default case sensitive, so to prevent from being in a situations where "pdf" is matched and "PDF" is not, the patter can be adjusted like this:

```
(?i)_(\d{8})\.pdf
```

You can than use it directly in any expression window:

[image]

PS: You should also ensure that `System.Text.RegularExpressions` reference is in the Imports:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by this way as well :)

> **Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Str1).Split("_"c).Last**

**Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension**

- Returns the file name of the specified path string without the extension.

so with your String it will return to you - **10001662-1_20060301_29_1_20190301**

then **Split** above String i.e. **10001662-1_20060301_29_1_20190301** based on **_** and will return an array of string.

**Last**

- It will return you the last element of an array returned by **Split.**.

Regards..!!
AKsh